# Three data sets in one plot in Tableau

Tags: tableau

The goal is to plot three data sets in one plot: (DATE1_GOOD, DATE1_BAD); (DATE2_GOOD, DATE2_BAD); (DATE3_GOOD, DATE3_BAD). Unfortunately, I'm getting all possible combinations:
[image]

So now the task is to combine the three diagonal plots into one and delete the rest since they make no sense. I tried dragging the axes but the result is not what I'm looking for, I get: (DATE3_GOOD, DATE1_BAD); (DATE3_GOOD, DATE2_BAD); (DATE3_GOOD, DATE3_BAD):
[image]
I'm new to Tableau, is it even possible to do what I want?

**EDIT**: @spectre In order to do this, I have to make the plots transparent somehow. How can I do this? I was trying but I always end up with something like below when using floating option [image]
and without floating [image]

Comment: The answer is given in stackoverflow by matt_black:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667207/three-data-sets-in-one-plot-in-tableau

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is plot the 3 graphs in 3 different pages and then combine them in a Dashboard. That way you can get all 3 graphs in one place. Below I have made 4 different graphs in different sheets and then combined all in one interactive Dashboard.

[image: The first graph]

[image: The second graph]

[image: The third graph]

[image: the fourth graph]

[image: all four graphs combined]

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Comment: @stolikp you do not need to make them transparent. Look @ my edited answer above.

Comment: OK. Now I understand what you were talking about. These are 4 neighboring plots on 1 dashboard. I wanted 3 lines in 1 plot (with 1 pair of axes), so that the lines could be compared. Thank you for your effort. My problem is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667207/three-data-sets-in-one-plot-in-tableau